# Получение данных из postgres с условиями

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, оптимизация-запросов

Нужна небольшая помощь по запросу.

ТО, ЧТО В ТАБЛИЦЕ 20й МЕСЯЦ - ОПЕЧАТКА.

Есть таблица, в которой отмечены ученики и их посещение уроков.

[image: пример таблицы]

Надо получиться выборку, какой урок за сегодня ученик посетил последним

**Запрос**

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date = (CURRENT_DATE) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Этот запрос вернет мне просто последние 5 id, а как получить уникальные name и Lesson?

Желаемый результат

```
11 Яна Литература    
10 Федор Литература    
 8 Григорий Математика    
 7 Олег География    
 6 Анна История
```

---

Буду рад любой помощи. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ROW_NUMBER в CTE.

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: [WITH Clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH), [ROW_NUMBER() function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html).

Comment: "ТО, ЧТО В ТАБЛИЦЕ 20й МЕСЯЦ - ОПЕЧАТКА." - тип колонки поменяйте на date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ваша задача абстрактный пример то что бы выделить первую или последнюю строку из группируемого диапазона вы можете воспользоваться оконной функцией first_value определив фрейм для поиска по имени ученика и дате проведения занятий:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, first_value(lesson) 
  OVER ( PARTITION BY name, date ORDER BY id DESC) FROM heap ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Так как коллеги согласны со мной, что это должен быть исключительно учебный пример, то если рассматривать варианты с подзапросом в плане производительности для PoatgreSQL представляет интерес подзапрос с LATERAL LIMIT без агрегатных функций:

```
SELECT DISTINCT h.name, l.lesson FROM heap h,
 LATERAL(SELECT lesson FROM heap WHERE name = h.name AND date = h.date ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) l 
 ORDER BY h.name DESC
```

Поэкспериментировать можно [здесь](https://dbfiddle.uk/R6AOu4g6)

Если вы что то создаете то это плохой вариант, так как вы свалили в одну кучу список учащихся, список предметов и журнал посещений. Это плохая схема данных.

Comment: Ваш вариант тоже рабочий. Больше спасибо, что подсказали решение. Задача была безусловно абстрактной.

Comment: Да не вопрос, можно рассмотреть так же варианты через CTE. Было бы неплохо если бы вы привели сам вопрос в соответствие с его сутью так как он на данный момент он ее не отражает. Вы просите помочь в условной фильтрации данных в подчиненном наборе но заголовок вашего вопроса не отражает сути. Я думаю что это делает его мало полезным для ваших последователей.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Дмитрий, за ваше внимание! Не могли бы вы посмотреть второй мой вопрос. Назван так же как и этот, только с пометкой 2.0   ---   Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что задача учебная,в противном случае не очень нравится уникальность учеников по строковому полю, но в целом для учебной задачи я бы предложил вариант с подзапросом, в котором выбирается максимальный ID (как я понимаю это номер записи о посещении, который растет по мере посещения занятий) за текущую дату по каждому из учеников:

```
 SELECT A.id, A.name, A.lesson FROM my_table A WHERE A.ID IN (SELECT max(id) from my_table WHERE date = CURRENT_DATE  GROUP BY name) ORDER BY id;
```

Тогда вывод будет таким (при условии, что 21-20-2023 мы все же поменяем на 2023-02-22 сегодня ):

```
1 Василий  Физика
3 Дмитрий  Химия
6 Анна     История
7 Олег     География
8 Григорий Математика
10 Федор   Литература
11 Яна     Литература
```

Comment: Да, задача более абстрактная, чем реальная. Для реального применения, безусловно, нужно нормализовать таблицу. Ваш вариант сработал, большое спасибо!

Comment: Не могли бы вы посмотреть второй мой вопрос. Назван так же как и этот, только с пометкой 2.0   ---   Заранее благодарен!